# Getting log on Android device

Tags: android, logging

I am trying to get the logs of some crashing apps.

I have two mobile devices and I need them to communicate over USB and use some apps. The apps don't do what they should. I can't connect the devices to the computer to analyze it, because their USB ports are connected to each other.

I tried to use TCP port forwarding and reach the logging info over wireless, but they are not in the same network with my PC and because of some organizational constraints I don't have the rights to build a wireless network between mobile device and PC. So I suppose port forwarding is out as well.

My idea is: If there is any logging app or a built-in logging feature of Android, I could watch the apps crash, save the logs in the mobile device and then download it to my PC and analyze it. (I know, it's not the same as simultaneously seeing the logging outputs but it's better than what I have now. For now, I have no idea what's going on between the two mobile devices.)

Any recommendations? I appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you save the stacktrace in a file? (if you're doing a try/catch ofc)

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I only have the binaries, I didn't write / don't have access to the code.